Calculate the distance from Q and P to $G_f$...
The problem
In the system of orthogonal axes xOy, we consider the points $P(a,b)$ and $Q(b, a)$ and note with $G_f$ the geometric representation of the graph of the function $f: R->R, f(x)=ax+ b, a,b\in R^*$ a and b being distinct.
a) Prove that the distance from P to $G_f$ does not depend on b.
b) Calculate the distance from Q to $G_f$
my idea
a)
I let $A(0,b), B(\frac{-b}{a},0)$, both on $G_f$
I tried calculating the area of $BAP$ using the fact that $A(ABP)=A(ABXP)-A(BPX)$, where $PX\perp Ox$ so $A(ABP)=A(ABXP)-A(BPX)=\frac{ab}{2}+\frac{b^2}{2}-\frac{ab}{2}-\frac{b^2}{2a}=\frac{ab}{2}= dis*AB:2=dis * \frac{b}{a}*\sqrt{a^2+1}:2$
So the distance from P to $G_f$ is $a^2*\sqrt{a^2+1}$, which doesn't depend on b
b) the same with point a I tried calculating the area of $BAQ$ using the fact that $A(BAQ)=A(ABYQ)-A(BQY)$, where $QY\perp Ox$ so  $A(BAQ)=A(ABYQ)-A(BQY)=\frac{b^2a-ab+b^2}{2a}=dis*\frac{b}{a}*\sqrt{a^2+1}:2$
So the distance from Q to $G_f$ is $\frac{ba-a+b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$
I'm not sure of my calculation and rationament on letting those points.Should I take two cases where $\frac{-b}{a}$ is positive and negative because it seems they are not the same
Hope one of you can tell me if I'm right or wrong! Thank you!

I edited my answer to point out your mistake...

I added some explanations in my answer. Do the explanations help?

@mathlove Yessssss...Thanks, now i clearly understand. I didn't knew with what $ab>0, <0$ helps. Thank you so much!!!!

a)
We have
$$A(ABP)=\frac{\text{dis}}{2}\times AB=\frac{\text{dis}\times |b|}{2|a|}\sqrt{a^2+1}\tag1$$
Case 1 : If $b\gt 0$, then we have
$$\begin{align}A(ABP)&=A(ABXP)-A(BPX)
\\\\&=\frac b2\bigg|a+\frac ba+a\bigg|-\frac b2\bigg|a+\frac ba\bigg|\end{align}$$
Therefore, from $(1)$, we get
$$\begin{align}\text{dis}&=\frac{2|a|}{b\sqrt{a^2+1}}\bigg(\frac b2\bigg|a+\frac ba+a\bigg|-\frac b2\bigg|a+\frac ba\bigg|\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\bigg(\bigg|a+\frac ba+a\bigg|-\bigg|a+\frac ba\bigg|\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\end{align}$$
Case 2 : If $b\lt 0$, then note that $A(ABP)=A(ABXP)-A(BPX)$ does not always hold. For example, take $a=-1$ and $b=-2$.
Here, we have
$$\begin{align}A(ABP)&=A(OAPB)-A(OAB)
\\\\&=\frac{-b}{2}\bigg(\bigg|a-\frac{b}{a}\bigg|-\bigg|\frac ba\bigg|\bigg)\end{align}$$
Therefore, from $(1)$, we get
$$\begin{align}\text{dis}&=\frac{2|a|}{-b\sqrt{a^2+1}}\times\frac{-b}{2}\bigg(\bigg|a-\frac{b}{a}\bigg|-\bigg|\frac ba\bigg|\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\end{align}$$

b)
Note that $A(BAQ)=A(ABYQ)-A(BQY)$ does not always hold. For example, take $a=2$ and $b=\frac 12$.
We have
$$A(BAQ)=\frac{\text{dis}}{2}\times AB=\frac{\text{dis}\times |b|}{2|a|}\sqrt{a^2+1}\tag2$$
Let $D(\frac{b^2}{b-a},0)$ be the intersection point of $QA$ with $x$-axis.
Case 1 : If $ab\gt 0$, then we have $$\begin{align}A(BAQ)&=\bigg|A(BDQ)-A(BDA)\bigg|
\\\\&=\frac{||a|-|b||}{2}\times\bigg|-\frac ba-\frac{b^2}{b-a}\bigg|
\\\\&=\frac{|b|\times|ab-a+b|}{2|a|}\end{align}$$
Therefore, from $(2)$, we have
$$\text{dis}=\frac{2|a|}{|b|\sqrt{a^2+1}}\times\frac{|b|\times|ab-a+b|}{2|a|}=\frac{|ab-a+b|}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$
Case 2 : If $ab\lt 0$, then we have
$$\begin{align}A(BAQ)&=A(BDQ)\color{red}+A(BDA)
\\\\&=\frac 12|b-a|\times\bigg|-\frac ba-\frac{b^2}{b-a}\bigg|
\\\\&=\frac{|b|\times |ab-a+b|}{2|a|}\end{align}$$
Therefore, from $(2)$, we have
$$\text{dis}=\frac{2|a|}{|b|\sqrt{a^2+1}}\times\frac{|b|\times|ab-a+b|}{2|a|}=\frac{|ab-a+b|}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$

Added :

i don't understand why he took those cases and how they influenced calculus of the area.

I think you are talking about b), so let me add some explanations about b).
The reason why I separated it into two cases ($ab\gt 0$ or $ab\lt 0$) is the followings :

If $ab\gt 0$, then since $A_y=b$ and $Q_y=a$ have the same sign, $D$ is not on the line segment $AQ$ (note that $D$ is on the line $AQ$ with $D_y=0$). Therefore, $A(BAQ)$ is equal to the difference between $A(BDQ)$ and $A(BDA)$, i.e. $$A(BAQ)=\bigg|A(BDQ)-A(BDA)\bigg|$$

If $ab\lt 0$, then since $A_y=b$ and $Q_y=a$ have different signs, $D$ is on the line segment $AQ$. Therefore, $A(BAQ)$ is equal to the sum of $A(BDQ)$ and $A(BDA)$.



$f(x)$ is a straight line. Perpendicular distance of a point from a straight line($mx+ny+c=0$) is given by $$d=\bigg|\frac{mx_1+ny_1+c}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}\bigg|$$
Now equation of line is $$ax-y+b=0,y=f(x)$$
Thus for $P(a,b)$,
$$d_P=\bigg|\frac{a^2+(-1)b+b}{\sqrt{a^2+(-1)^2}}\bigg|=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$
Applying same formula for $Q$ gives
$$d_Q=\bigg|\frac{ab-a+b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\bigg|$$
Proof of formula used
$$Ar(ABP)=\frac{ab}{2}=\frac{1}{2}d_P×AB$$
By distance formula, $$AB=\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{-b}{a}\bigg)^2+b^2}$$
So $$ab=d_p×b\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+1}\implies d_P=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$
Modulus is required as distance should always be positive. Actually if $u=\sqrt{v^2}\implies u=|v|$
Also $x_1,y_1$ are coordinates of the point from which we are measuring the distance

Thanks for your answer! 2 questions: 1) what does $x_1, y_1$ mean 2) Can you tell me where did I go wrong...Did I have to make all the calc with modules?

$x_1,y_1$ means the coordinates of the point from whom we are calculating the distance @IONELABUCIU . I'm trying to rectify your method

Ok,I saw your edit... how did you calculate the area of BAP, because we don't know if $\frac{-b}{a}$ is positive or not so we have to use modules and I don't arrive to the same form using modules. Thank you again

You made a typo, it should be $d(P,G_f)=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$ instead of $a^2\sqrt{a^2+1}$. Also, $ba-a+b$ can be negative, so you have to take the absolute value of that in part b). Otherwise, your method is fine assuming $a\neq 0$ (this special case can easily be solved separately). Another way to solve this is by noting that if $X=(x,f(x))$, then $d(P,X)=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(f(x)-b)^2}=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(ax)^2}$, which doesn't depend on $b$. Also $d(P,G_f)=inf_{X\in G_f}d(X,P)$ .
Since $(a-x)^2+(ax)^2$ is a parabola that attains its minimum at $x_{min}=\frac{a}{a^2+1}$, we have $d(P,G_f)=\sqrt{(a-x_{min})^2+(ax_{min})^2}=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$.
Similarily, $d(Q,X)=\sqrt{(b-x)^2+(ax+b-a)^2}$. The parabola $(b-x)^2+(ax+b-a)^2$ attains its minimum at $x_{min}=\frac{a^2-ab+b}{a^2+1}$. Hence $d(Q,G_f)=\sqrt{(b-x_{min})^2+(ax_{min}+b-a)^2}=\frac{|ab-a+b|}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$

Can you look at my edit? I think my idea sint correct..i think i need to work with modules
